# C compiler not noticing errors and correcting code itself

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, compilation, mingw

So I am a beginner in C and I have been following a book Primer Plus 6th edition.
While I was running my program I noticed something really strange, compiler is not working as it is supposed to, for example

```
int main(){
    one_three();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void one_three(void){
    printf("one\n");
    two();
    printf("three");
}

void two(void){
    printf("two\n");

}
```

this is my code, there are many errors as no function prototype declarations and not including header files, but some how the output is produced only by giving warnings, i dont think this should happen
***NOTE I HAVE INTENTIONALLY REMOVED FUNCTION PROTOTYPE DECLARTAIONS AND INCLUDING HEADER FILES***

output is :

```
review1.c: In function 'main':
review1.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'one_three' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    2 |     one_three();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
review1.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getchar' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    3 |     getchar();
      |     ^~~~~~~
review1.c:1:1: note: 'getchar' is defined in header '<stdio.h>'; did you forget to '#include <stdio.h>'?
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
    1 | int main(){
review1.c: At top level:
review1.c:7:6: warning: conflicting types for 'one_three'
    7 | void one_three(void){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
review1.c:2:5: note: previous implicit declaration of 'one_three' was here
    2 |     one_three();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
review1.c: In function 'one_three':
review1.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    8 |     printf("one\n");
      |     ^~~~~~
review1.c:8:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
review1.c:8:5: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
review1.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'two' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |     two();
      |     ^~~
review1.c: At top level:
review1.c:13:6: warning: conflicting types for 'two'
   13 | void two(void){
      |      ^~~
review1.c:9:5: note: previous implicit declaration of 'two' was here
    9 |     two();
      |     ^~~
review1.c: In function 'two':
review1.c:14:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
   14 |     printf("two\n");
      |     ^~~~~~
review1.c:14:5: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
one 
two
three
```

those last three lines "one" two three is the output
Please help, i am using this compiler

[image]

I expect it to output errors when it has to and not add stuff itself, so that i could learn by my mistakes
using visual studio code with extensions : C/C++ by microsoft, Code runner

Comment: What you get are *warnings*, not errors. Warning are just diagnostic messages the compiler will use to tell  you that you're doing something that is technically valid C but you really shouldn't be doing. You should treat warnings as errors.

Comment: but not specifying function delcaration and no header files?
how is that valid

Comment: Because in C when you use a function that haven't been declared yet, the compiler is allowed to *implicitly* declare it. It uses the types of the arguments you pass, and the function will always return an `int`. The C99 standard actually removed that, but it seems GCC still allows it (but generates a warning about it).

Comment: so in every C compiler, this code will issue same warnings ? and will implicitly declare functions such they have return type int

Comment: For GCC, add `-Werror` the command line, and it will elevate all warnings to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier pre-standard versions of C had the concept of a default type given to objects if they weren't explicitly given a type.  Functions, if not declared, were implicitly typed as:

```
int func();
```

So a function without a prototype was assumed to return `int` and take an unspecified number of arguments.  Because old code was written with this in mind, many compilers are backward compatible and compile old code such as this, but issues warnings when these old constructs are used.

In your particular case, you're able to get away with the implicit function declarations of the functions you define because the functions have `void` return type and no attempt is made to use the return value of these functions.  For the `getchar` and `printf` functions, their return type is `int` so they can work with the implicit declaration.

Comment: thank you so much
so how would you change the same code such that compiler does not performs implicit declarations?by changing return types ?
Just want to clear this out 
thanks once again

Comment: @AliAsifKhan For library function, you would include the proper header files.  In your case you would `#include <stdio.h>`.  For your own functions, either define the functions before they are used or create a declaration at the top of the file for each function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare methods that you are using in functions above the functions you are using them in. If you reorder the functions to be two, then one_three, then main. It should work.